# How do I install TikZ into my MiKTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, miktex

How do I install the TikZ package to my current MiKTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.  As for TikZ, see http://docs.miktex.org/faq/packages.html or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: @SeanAllred, maybe this question is a duplicate of this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: @MarioS.E. That's the closest one I've seen so far, but I'm wary that it doesn't specifically say "How do I install * package?"

Answer (score 1):

write:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

or

```
\usepackage{pgf} %if you only want the base layer
```

in your preamble

Or, as Sean mentioned, you can go through your MikTeX package manager

Comment: At any rate, it would be good to go over the Package Manager approach as well, so one could install any and all packages desired more easily.

Comment: Hi When I have included those things in preamble even following code does not show anything without any compilation errors      \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @Priyanha, you can try looking at these two .pdf: http://mirrors.linsrv.net/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf and http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no luck whatsoever. Without any compilation errors even a simple code like                     \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) --(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}                                                              produce no picture at all!!! I am going really mad!!

Comment: maybe you can ask a new question.  Please make sure to include a Minimal (Non) Working Example in it.

Comment: Mario, thanks for your constant helps!! Now I found the error, I think! It is that I have included \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} also in my preamble. Without it TikZ commands work, it seems!! Thanks and cheers to all of you!!!!

Comment: @Priyanha `graphicx` should not have any incompatibility issues with `tikz`.  I think it is because of the optional `dvips` that you were experiencing the problem